# What ticket option should I pick for a train journey from Paris to Meaux?

Tags: trains, paris, sncf

I have the SNCF connect app on my phone and see the following ticket options. There are also the monthly and weekly pass not shown in the image but I don't want them. I want to buy a single ticket from Paris Gare du Nord to Meaux and back. Should I buy a t+ ticket for this or something else?

[image]

The t+ ticket doesn't specify zones and my understanding is that Meaux is in Zone 5. Is a single t+ tickets for 2.15 euros (or 10 such t+ tickets for 17,35) valid for my journey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a t+ ticket is valid only for:

- One trip on the metro (for now, to any place on the Metro network, but this will soon change)
- One trip on the RER in Zone 1 only
- One trip combining any of the above
- One trip on a bus
- One trip on a tramway
- One trip combining bus and tramway

Trips on Transilien trains and RER outside of zone 1 cannot be made using a t+ ticket.

Sadly, you can't use a Navigo card or phone for a single trip which does not match the t+ requirements. You need to buy a paper ticket at an SNCF or RATP station.

The alternative is to buy a Navigo day pass for zones 1 to 5, but that is quite a bit more expensive: a single ticket for that trip is currently 5 €, while a Navigo day pass for zones 1 to 5 is 20.60 €. Unless you need a return and have a more relatively trips planned (e.g. to/from airport) this is unlikely to be worth it.

Also note that trains to Meaux leave from Gare de l'Est, not Gare du Nord.

Comment: Another note: the Paris-suburb ticket lets you start/end at any metro/RER station in Paris. On the other hand, it is not valid for an extra bus/tram journey at either end.

Comment: You can also buy Orlybus and Roissybus on an NFC phone now. But not tickets for other suburban trips.